# Trying to get a python script to run full screen without letting window be re-sized or menu bar showing

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, display

I am trying to make a product using one of the new rpi touchscreens. I have a python script I boot into that makes a window using tkinter with 800x480 resolution to match the screen, but my user can still drag their finger from the edge of the screen and re-size the window. The user can also touch where I hid the menu bar, popping it up, allowing them to exit or minimize the python script. I want neither to happen, as the user should be stuck in the python script during normal use to avoid confusion.

Best, DL

Comment: are you familiar with tkinter's [overrideredirect](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method) setting?

Comment: I am not, I am reading the link you sent now.

Comment: @bryan I tried the overrideredirect(true) and now it does not want to run due to the wrong tkinter being needed. any suggestion

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "wrong tkinter being needed". It works with either version of tkinter. If you're using python3 it's `tkinter` and if you're using python it's `Tkinter`.

Comment: Sorry about that, stupid mistake on my side, was accidentally running in python2.7 and not 3. It is closer to working now, it appears to be full screen but is shifted up ~15 pixels where the top of my interface is cut off and the desktop is showing on the bottom. Thanks again!

Comment: Just a quick update, I figured out the screen shift problem and everything is all good now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you please show me how you did, I got the same problem